# Craft login redirecting to /web instead of /templates?

Tags: redirect, login

I've moved my Craft directory to the below:

```
Templates
Public_Html
Web
etc..
etc..
```

My previous directory when I installed was:

```
Public_html > Craft-setup > Web > Templates
```

Now when I login from the front-end as a user, I get taken to the old directory even though it's empty,

```
example.com/craft-setup/web/
```

The actual directory it should be taking me to is

```
example.com/
```

As my index.php craft file is in public_html

What is the correct method to update the redirect to go to the correct place?

I can access my site perfectly fine and use it by going to example.com/ i'm assuming my base path is fine as the site loads and functions by going to the domain, so why is the front-end login taking me to the old directory? this is the login form I'm talking about https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I found it, needed to change the SiteURL in .env file.